# Merge columns in pandas to excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a `pandas` dataframe to excel where certain **columns** are merged. I know it is possible to merge rows like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal": ("horse", "horse", "dog", "dog"), "color": ("black", "white", "grey", "black")})

df.to_excel("some_path_here")
```

[image: row_merge]

But I'm unsure how to create output like the following, where columns are merged:

[image: column_merge]

I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal": "color of fur", "horse": "black", "horse": "white", "dog": "grey", "dog": "black"})

df.to_excel("some_path_here")
```

But that doesn't work because the keys will overwrite each other. Any tips?

(this example isn't the most logical but I will use it differently in my project)

Comment: You have to use an excel writer. There is no straightforward way to accomplish what you want with pandas as far as I know. You have to use something like `openpyxl`

Comment: have you tried `pandas multiindex`?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: @BSP `multiindex` seems like something that could work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create transposed output as described, try a 2-stage process to first tranpose the data in Pandas then use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to merge the cells for columns when the animal is the same. With openpyxl you can merge cells, set cell alignment, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"animal": ("horse", "horse", "dog", "dog"), "color": ("black", "white", "grey", "black")})

df1 = df.transpose()
df1.to_excel("out1.xlsx")
```

This creates structure:

```
            0      1     2      3
animal  horse  horse   dog    dog
color   black  white  grey  black
```

Next use *openpyxl* to merge the cells, set cell alignment to center, etc.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import colors, Font
from openpyxl.styles.alignment import Alignment

wb = load_workbook(filename="out1.xlsx", data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# delete first row with numbers
ws.delete_rows(1)

last_animal = ''
font = Font(name='Arial', b=True)
for col in range(2, ws.max_column+1):
    cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=col)
    if last_animal == cell.value:
        ws.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=col-1, end_row=1, end_column=col)
        # set BOLD font and center alignment on cell
        cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=col-1)
        cell.font = font
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center")
    last_animal = cell.value
wb.save('out2.xlsx')
```

**Output:**

[image: excel output]

You can further tweak and customize the Excel output using the openpyxl API.

Comment: I don't see how this is the output that I want? Because this still doesn't group the columns together

Comment: Updated answer: can transpose rows and columns using `df1 = df.transpose()` in pandas then use openpyxml to merge the cells.

Comment: That looks great, but are you also able to get rid of the numbers in the first row?

Comment: add `ws.delete_rows(1)`

Comment: Now it's perfect, thanks a lot!